# Outlook 2013 Inbox synchronizes but does not download email

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap

My inbox in Outlook 2013 synchronizes, but no emails are downloaded. Other folders download fine. I tried the "workaround that always works" in another thread

(WORKAROUND THAT ALWAYS WORKS) 
 4. If all above fails, add the IMAP account again so you have two instances on the same profile. Set the newly added IMAP instance as the default (this also changes the default data store). Allow Outlook time to move data to the new instance, then remove the old account instance.)

but same problem, i.e. all folders in the new account except Inbox download. I have set the new account as default. No messages in sync issues. I use W 8.1.
Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems something in your outlook profile has gone corrupt. You should do the following:

1. Press WIN+I, then click Control Panel
2. Go to E-mail 32 bit (or mail 32 bit)
3. Go to profiles
4. Press Add to create a new profile
5. Add the email address(es)
6. When back to the profiles screen, make sure your new profile is set to default.

Now try again. If all works, and you don't need your old profile anymore, you can remove the profile.

Comment: Did so, including setting the new account to default, and every folder except Inbox and Sent Items download. Inbox synchronizes, but stops quickly with no action. Sync issues folder did not appear on new account.

Comment: Open the webmail version of your IMAP account, and verify that there are indeed other emails to be downloaded. For all you know, it isn't and you're chasing a ghost.

Comment: No problems with webmail, everything is there. No mails at all are downloaded to Inbox and Sent Items, these Outlook folders are empty.

Comment: Is it possible that these folders are somehow translated and that you're looking at a different inbox and sent items?

Comment: Seems unlikely. Drafts folder has downloaded only to Dec 10, same day as the problems began. But from Dec 10 and backwards, the contents of the webmail folder matches that of Outlook. No problems sending with Outlook and the emails appear in the correct webmail folder.

Comment: Last thing I can think of is exporting all email, delete the account on the server, and recreate it. In order to export all mail from the inbox and other folders you can't sync, use webmail to move all email to a different folder so they all show up in outlook. From there export everything to a .PST file, and on the new account, import everything.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but I contacted my ISP again when I realized that my iPhone stopped downloading emails at the same time as Outlook on the computer. When I called them previously they said there were no problems on their end, but this time they admitted to having moved my email to another server that day! So sorry to have bothered you with my question, and thanks for trying to help me resolve it, when the fault was with the ISP all the time!